# It seems that British people do not have inclination to pronounce some "r", but why?

Tags: pronunciation

Why British people do not pronounce most "r" which is mostly located at the the end of word? for example :

There: UK /ðeə(r)/ and    US /ðer/
therefrom: UK /ˌðeəˈfrɒm/ and US  /ˌðerˈfrɑːm/
More:UK  /mɔː(r)/ and US  /mɔːr/

and sometimes they do not pronounce two "r" in one word, as:
Therefore: UK  /ˈðeə.fɔːr/ US  /ˈðer.fɔːr/

Comment: Or, reversed, American people pronounce too many of their r sounds. I don’t think there’s really a *reason*, per se; it just is. Although it’s possible someone will come in and correct me on that.

Comment: @Fivesideddice yes you are right, we can look from that other side, why American people pronounce all "r". In some other language like French, they, like British, do not pronounce some character like "h" or characters being at the end of a word. But in my native language, we pronounce all characters, like American people, although our language is totally different. But English is identical for American, Canadian, Australian and British.

Comment: Do you see what your examples have in common? They all begin with "th". Why don't you look up some words that begin with other letters but contain the letter "r"? For example: *butter, more, fear, sore*, and *theatre*, and then rethink your analysis.

Comment: Not every "r" is pronounced by all American English speakers. Not every "r" is silent in British English. Look up **rhotic r** for more information.

Comment: The only reason is that the language has evolved that way. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English

Comment: Dear @Mari-LouA you added good examples, butter, more, sore, etc. thank you. I just give those, i.e. therefore, etc. as an example. About this: "Not every "r" is pronounced by all American English speakers", Could you give an example? about "rhotic", its "r" is not at the end of word.

Comment: Many dialects in the Northeastern United States drop 'r' sounds. The sentence illustrating the stereotypical Boston accent is, "Pahk the cah in Hahvahd Yahd," (that is, "Park the car in Harvard Yard").

Comment: Dear @CanadianYankee I did not know that, thanks for putting forward this matter.